# fill in the text box and click on search button - webscraping using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i am trying to web scrape few information from a web page.

I need to send input like text or email ID and then click on the search icon .

I tried below,

```
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("headerSearchKeyword")
inputElement.send_keys('ID1234')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('top-search').click()
```

it throws error

> WebDriverException: unknown error: call function result missing
> 'value'   (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)   (Driver info:
> chromedriver=2.25.426923
> (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT
> 10.0.15063 x86_64)

Any help?

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks DebajanB , the link worked, i was using the older version

Answer (score 1):

In CSS selector the class value starts with dot(.). Please try with dot as given below.

```
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("headerSearchKeyword")
inputElement.send_keys('ID1234')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.top-search').click()
```

Comment: inputElement.send_keys('ID1234') This line sends the same error. I have no idea :( . The third line is fine

Comment: Hi Murthi, i was using older version. upgrading worked for me. thanks much for the response